# Name of the category of foreign words with no english translation

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the name of this type of word which does not have a one word English translation.  Words such as:

Waldeinsamkeit
(German) The feeling of being alone in the woods. Some Hansel and Gretel or Red Riding Hood reference, I bet!

Tartle
(Scottish) If you’ve ever been talking to someone you’ve been introduced to before but their name has completely disappeared from your brain then you’ve tartled. Essentially means a hesitation in recognising a person or thing.

(I want to be able to research this type of word by entering something besides: foreign words with no English translation.  I thought these words might have a name.)

Comment: I've seen them called simply 'untranslatables'.

Comment: @KateBunting You should post this as an answer. It is a good word since it covers also the reverse category of English words which have no equivalent in many foreign languages. The word "home" for example has no real equivalent in French. French people do not do things "at home" but "à la maison".

Comment: Strictly, there is an expression for ‘at home’:  ‘chez eux’ (or ´chez moi/mon frère/Yolande....’).  But I agree that ‘untranslatables’ is worth writing into an answer.  I was going to suggest that the adjective might be better, but that is my own grumpy-old-linguist’s dislike of the forced conversion of adjectives into nouns and vice versa!

Comment: _Wald + Einsamkeit_ = woodland solitude

Comment: @Tuffy Yes, you can do the "chez...* thing, but how about "home improvements", or "home is where the heart is", or "how to turn a house into a home". It starts to get difficult. Another difficult word is "cosy*. How do you say, in French, "what a cosy little home you have"?

Comment: @WS2 True.  But doesn’t that move us from specific ‘untranslatable’ words to the fact that the outside science and mathematics few words have the same ‘field of meaning’ in other languages, just as animals and birds do not evolve in the same way in different islands of the Galapagos.  That is what makes the art of translation so interesting.

Answer (score 1):

A [loanword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword) is an untranslated word from another language.  English has a great many of these, from French in particular.

Comment: but a loan word is not necessarily untranslatable.

Comment: The question says "foreign words with no english translation", which I took to mean "without a **single-word** English equivalent".  That doesn't mean that they have to be "untranslatable".  What would it even mean for something to be "untranslatable"?  Any foreign concept can be translated into English, though not necessarily with a single word.

Answer (score 0):

[Foreignism](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/foreignism)  defines what you are referring to:

> - any trait, deviating from accepted speech standards, derived from a foreign language.

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: What an awful word! It does have an entry in the OED, but I am glad to see that it doesn't appear to have been used since 1887! *An idiom, phrase, or term of foreign origin.
1877   Congregationalist (U.S.) 15 Aug.   That he [Miles Coverdale] left in his Bible some few foreignisms..is not surprising.
1887   L. Swinburne in Scribner's Mag. 2 508   It is astonishing, indeed, how many of these foreignisms have crept into the common speech.*

Comment: @WS2 it does sound rather hateful eh.

Comment: Good try.  However, that sounds as if it has pejorative (is that word a foreignism?)  overtones.

Comment: @WS2 - there are much earlier usage instances. https://books.google.it/books?id=NSSA0CcNITwC&pg=PA201&dq=%22foreignism%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj42_rnjI3eAhWBiSwKHQz-CaIQ6AEIZzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22foreignism%22&f=false - and apart from the OED, the term has an entry in all common dictionaries.

Comment: @Tuffy - I agree it may convey a sense of "criticism" and probably "frustration" for having to use a  foreign word/idiom, but it is not necessarily so.

Answer (score 0):

Simply regard it **[untranslatable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/untranslatable)**.

"untranslatable"

**ADJECTIVE**

> (of a word, phrase, or text) not
>   able to have its sense
>   expressed in another
>   language.

---

Following are some of the untranslatable words:

1. Waldeinsamkeit (German)
2. Iktsuarpok (Inuit)
3. Komorebi (Japanese)
4. Sobremesa (Spanish)
5. Goya (Urdu)
6. Mångata (Swedish)
7. Saudade (Portuguese)
8. Kilig (Tagalog)
9. Hiraeth (Welsh)
10. Mamihlapinatapei (Yaghan)

**Footnotes:**

> - [20
>     of the world's most beautiful untranslatable words](https://www.rocketlanguages.com/blog/20-of-the-worlds-most-beautiful-untranslatable-words/)